# multiply by integer using tMap

Tags: java, talend, tmap

I want to calculate a percentage but when I multiply by 100 I get an error :  `bigdecimal is not defined for the type Im`
[image: here is the expression]
[image: the Job][image: tMap schema]

Answer (score 0):

- Try with **new BigDecimal("100")** instead of BigDecimal(100).
- Then perhaps you'll have to use Rounding and precision in your divide method, depending on your data : row1.col1.multiply(new BigDecimal("100")).divide(row1.col2,5,java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP);